# Jmeter posting json application

Tags: json, playframework, jmeter

Hello I have got problem I have configured my Jmeter to test performance between play framework version 2.2 and 2.3 to check the speed of controllers but when I post something (here im creating account) in play console I see that account is creating but its not saving in my database, when I have done this same from another laptop by typing my IP Adress it saved it to database and worked good. I dont know where could be the problem cause configuration is the same.

In Jmaker in thread I have made

HTTP Head Manager and i added here

Name: Content-Type Value: application/json

I have made too HTTP Request

Server Adress: localhost Port:9000  Method: Post   Content encoding: UTF-8

Path: api/accounts   Implementation: HTTPClient 4  Portocol [http]: http

And in parameters I added

name:(nothing),
Value:{"username":"AccountTest1","password":"test6ccou49","email":"AccountTest1@dev.null"}

and I have turned only Include Equals

I added to Constant Timer and jp@gc Response Times over time from plugin which is making chart

I dont know why when I press Start: chart is building, in play console I see account creating but this is not saving to database.

I will be very thankful for every help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a CSV file like below sample data:

> AccountTest1,test6ccou49,AccountTest1@dev.null
>   AccountTest2,test6ccou50,AccountTest2@dev.null
>   AccountTest3,test6ccou51,AccountTest3@dev.null
>   ..... so on

Add->Config Element->CSV Data Set Config

keep settings as mentioned below:

> Filename: "Give complete file path with file name e.g. c:\folder1\folder2\file.csv"
>   File Encoding: "Leave Blank"
>   Variable Names: "user_name,pass_wd,e_mail"
>   Delimiter: ","
>   Allow Quoted Data: "false"
>   Recycle on EOF: "True"
>   Stop Thread on EOF: "false"
>   Sharing mode: "All threads"

Now Post body should look like

> {"username":"${user_name}","password":"${pass_wd}","email":"${e_mail}"}

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use "Post Body" in the HTTP Sampler to post below values

> {"username":"AccountTest1","password":"test6ccou49","email":"AccountTest1@dev.null"}

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I have repaired it already, the problem was in Http Header :), I have got question, now I'm creating accounts by requesting

```
  {"username":"AccountTest1","password":"test6ccou49","email":"AccountTest1@dev.null"}
```

But this create one account, I was testing some solutions on the Internet but them don't work also is here any way to make a lot of accounts in one time to test performance?

My create account function gets json object {xxx:yyy,bbb:ccc}